# How do I reference previous/next rows when iterating through a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this (I'm simplifying slightly here):

Column 1 has a user id
Column 2 has a url title
Column 3 has an actual url

The data is already ordered by user and time. So its User 1 and all the URLs they visited in ascending order of time and then User 2 and the URLs they visited in ascending order of time etc etc

What I'm trying to do is loop through the dataset and look for "triplets" where the first rows url doesn't contain my keyword (something like google or facebook or nytimes or whatever), the second rows url does contain my keyword, and the third row doesn't contain my keyword. Basically checking to see which websites users visited before and after any specific website.

I've figured out I can look for the keyword using:

```
if(length(grep("facebook",url)) > 0)
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to loop through the code and achieve what I'm trying to do.

If you could break your response into two parts, I would really appreciate it:

Part 1: Is there any way to loop through a dataframe and have access to all the columns? I was able to work on a single column with this code:

```
 new_data <- data.frame (url)

 for (url in data$url)
    if(length(grep("keyword",url)) > 0) {
     new_data <- rbind(new_data,data.frame(url = url))
   }
```

This approach is limited though because I can only reference a single column in my dataframe. Whats the better solution here? I tried:

- for (row in data) and then referencing columns by row[column_number] and row['column_name'] to no   avail
- I also tried for (i in 1:nrow(data)) and then referencing columns using data[i,column_number] and that didn't work either (That should have worked right?) I figured if this method worked I could use i-1 and i+1 to access other rows! I know this isn't the traditional way of doing things in R, but if you could still offer an explanation on how to do it this way I would really appreciate it.

Part 2: How do I accomplish my actual goal, as stated earlier? I'd like to learn to do it the "R way"; I imagine its going to involve plyr or lapply, but I haven't managed to figure out how to use those functions even after extensive reading, let alone use them and include references to previous/next rows.

Thanks in advance for your help, any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: You should add some sample data to make the question clearer.  But, if I understand, maybe you could use a row counter, ir=2:(nrow(df)-1); irp1=ir+1; irm1=ir-1;  then match_row <- grep('findURL',df$url[ir]); match_mrow <- grep('findURL',df$url[irm1]); match_prow <- grep('findURL',df$url[irp1]);  sol<-union(union(match_row,match_prow),match_mrow)

Comment: Honestly, I would use a `for` loop. It's not terribly idiomatic to use in R, but for this problem it's the least worst option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[-1]`:

```
last <- nrow(df)
penu <- nrow(df) - 1

df$ContainsKeyword <- FALSE
df$ContainsKeyword[grep("keyword", df$url)] <- TRUE
df$TripletFound <- NA
   for (i in 2:penu){
     df$TripletFound[i] <- {df$ContainsKeyword[i-1] & df$ContainsKeyword[i+1]} & {!df$ContainsKeyword[i]}

   }
```

Comment: There may be a better solution by comparing `df$ContainsKeyword[-(1:2)]` to `df$ContainsKeyword[-c(penu,last)]`.